# Sliding window iteration in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I'm creating a small library of Python utilities, and I'd like feedback on a function which allows iterating over an arbitrary iterable in a sliding-window fashion.

Relevant parts of `iteration.py`:

```
import collections
import itertools


def sliding_window_iter(iterable, size):
    """Iterate through iterable using a sliding window of several elements.

    Creates an iterable where each element is a tuple of `size`
    consecutive elements from `iterable`, advancing by 1 element each
    time. For example:

    >>> list(sliding_window_iter([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))
    [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
    """
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    window = collections.deque(
        itertools.islice(iterable, size-1),
        maxlen=size
    )
    for item in iterable:
        window.append(item)
        yield tuple(window)
```

Relevant parts of the test file `iteration_test.py`:

```
import doctest
import unittest

import iteration
from iteration import *


class TestSlidingWindowIter(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_good(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(sliding_window_iter([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)),
            [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
        )

    def test_exact_length(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(sliding_window_iter(["c", "b", "a"], 3)),
            [("c", "b", "a")]
        )

    def test_short(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(sliding_window_iter([1, 2], 3)),
            []
        )

    def test_size_one(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(sliding_window_iter([1, 2, 3, 4], 1)),
            [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
        )

    def test_bad_size(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            list(sliding_window_iter([1, 2], 0))


def run():
    if not doctest.testmod(iteration)[0]:
        print("doctest: OK")
    unittest.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

I'm primarily looking for feedback in these areas:

- Is the code Pythonic? I'm primarily a C++ developer, so Python idioms don't come naturally to me; that's one thing I'm constantly trying to improve.
- Are there any potential performance problems?
- Am I reinventing a wheel and something like this already exists?

I'll welcome any other feedback too, of course.

Comment: As for the last question, of course you are. See _rolling_ or _more-itertools_ on PyPI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks pretty good to me. You are taking advantage of the standard library, are following the relevant style guides and you even have tests, good job!

Personally, I am more in favor of using `import from`, at least for well-known standard library functions and maybe for utility functions that are used everywhere throughout a project. This way you can more often fit the code on one line easily, making it more readable.

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import deque
```

One small improvement is that your initial slice can be one larger, the argument behaves just like a range or slice argument and is exclusive of the end (i.e `islice(x, 4)` takes the first four elements since it is analogous to `x[0:4]`, `x[:4]` and `range(0, 4)`). However, this way you need to deal with the last element in a special way, so YMMV:

```
def sliding_window_iter(iterable, size):
    """..."""
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    window = deque(islice(iterable, size), maxlen=size)
    for item in iterable:
        yield tuple(window)
        window.append(item)
    if window:  
        # needed because if iterable was already empty before the `for`,
        # then the window would be yielded twice.
        yield tuple(window)
```

This also reveals one behavior which you should at least be aware of (which seems to be the case, since you have a test for it). Arguable, `sliding_window_iter([1, 2], 3)` could yield `(1, 2)`, i.e. the function maybe shouldn't swallow any data. In any case, the chosen behavior should be documented in the docstring.

Comment: Thanks! I actually consider "swallow data if too short" a feature, as my original motivation for this utility was computing differences of adjacent elements etc., and passing a further function a tuple shorter than it expects didn't sound healthy. On the other hand, I can imagine applications where yielding the shorter one would be preferable. Do you think adding an optional parameter like `, allow_smaller=False` would be a good idea?

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO: Yeah, that might be a good compromise. Whether you add it or not, the (default) behaviour should be documented in the docstring.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  I thought using `deque()` like the original code would be slow, but it is actually faster than most I tried.  For reasonable window sizes the code below runs in 2/3 the time. In some tests with large windows (>= 100), it was slower, but not always.

```
from itertools import islice, tee

def sliding_window_iter4(iterable, size):
    iterables = tee(iter(iterable), size)
    window = zip(*(islice(t, n, None) for n,t in enumerate(iterables)))
    yield from window
```